# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'item'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plot the data

```py
def show_data(data_sample):
    plt.imshow(data_sample[0].numpy().reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
    plt.title('y = ' + str(data_sample[1].item()))

# Print the first image and label

print("First Image and Label", show_data(train_dataset[0]))
```

Error:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 3
      1 # Print the first image and label
----> 3 print("First Image and Label", show_data(train_dataset[0]))

Cell In[31], line 5, in show_data(data_sample)
      3 def show_data(data_sample):
      4     plt.imshow(data_sample[0].numpy().reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
----> 5     plt.title('y =' + str(data_sample[1].item()))

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'item'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can't help you if you don't provide more detail about what `train_dataset` is and is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

tell me if I am wrong, as you didn't give much of information, but it looks like you want to use a list `data_sample` to show it the way you want thanks to the numpy module.

Here, you are calling the `item` method wich doesn't exist for an int type in python so this is what the error says.

However, if you want to get the `value` of a list, you only need to write `list[index_of_item]`to get the item from your list. If you have stored tuples in your list, then you can get their value by using multpiple hooks. It would look like this `list[first_index][second_index]` and so on ...

Do not forget that lists in python starts from `index = 0` so if you want to call the first item of your list you should write : `list[0]`. Also, if you need to call the last item of your list, you can write `list[-1]`.

I hope my answer is clear enough as your question wasn't really so please, next time you ask a question, make sure it respects the [minimal reproductible exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).